# Defining and summing object in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Program should count salary for different employees. 
Here is the code:

```
class Pracownik:
    def __init__(self, imie, wynagrodzenie_brutto):
        self.imie=imie
        self.wynagrodzenie_brutto=wynagrodzenie_brutto
    def wynagrodzenie_netto(self):
        skladki_pracownik=round(0.1371*self.wynagrodzenie_brutto,2)
        zdrowotne=round((self.wynagrodzenie_brutto-skladki_pracownik)*0.09,2)
        zdrowotne_odliczenie=round((self.wynagrodzenie_brutto-skladki_pracownik)*0.0775,2)
        kup=111.25
        zaliczka_podstawa=round(self.wynagrodzenie_brutto-kup-skladki_pracownik,2)
        zaliczka_pobrana=round((zaliczka_podstawa*0.18)-zdrowotne_odliczenie-46.33,0)
        netto=round(self.wynagrodzenie_brutto-skladki_pracownik-zdrowotne-zaliczka_pobrana,2)
        return netto
    def skladki_pracodawcy(self):
        skladki_pracodawca=round(self.wynagrodzenie_brutto*0.2074,2)
        return skladki_pracodawca
    def koszty_calkowite(self):
        calosc=round(self.wynagrodzenie_brutto+self.skladki_pracodawcy(),2)
        return calosc
    def __str__(self):
        return str((self.wynagrodzenie_netto(), self.skladki_pracodawcy(), self.koszty_calkowite()))
pracownik1=Pracownik("jan", 1680)
print(pracownik1)
```

Now it works correctly but only for one employee. 
It should works for a specific number of employee i.e.:
input

```
2
John 2580
Greg 1680
```

where 2 is the number of employees and after we have name of employee and salary. 
Output:

```
John 1863.91 535.09 3115.09
Greg 1237.20 348.43 2028.43
5143.52
```

where 5143.52 is total of last numbers (sum of self.koszty_calkowite() for all employees).

I tried:

```
for i in range(s):
    pracownik=Pracownik(input(),input())
    print(pracownik)
```

to print all objects but it doesn't work. 
Any idea how to get an output (all objects and sum)?

Comment: `it doesn't work` provide more detail

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pensja.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(pracownik)
  File "pensja.py", line 24, in __str__
    return str((self.wynagrodzenie_netto(), self.skladki_pracodawcy(), self.koszty_calkowite()))
  File "pensja.py", line 9, in wynagrodzenie_netto
    skladki_pracownik=round(0.1371*self.wynagrodzenie_brutto,2)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: `input()` takes the user input and puts it in a string. You should convert the inputted values to int/floats first

Comment: s=int(input())    pracownik=Pracownik(input(),int(input())) like that? First input in Pracownik is a name so it couldn't be int value

Comment: Yes try that and let me know

Comment: After changes: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pensja.py", line 27, in <module>
    pracownik=Pracownik(input(),int(input()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'greg 1500'

Comment: Maybe I should split the name and the value but where and how?

Comment: I posted an example of how to work with the values `input()` gives in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer after comments

---

I adjusted your code here and there:

```
class Pracownik:
    total = 0.0

    def __init__(self, imie, wynagrodzenie_brutto):
        self.imie=imie
        self.wynagrodzenie_brutto=wynagrodzenie_brutto

    def wynagrodzenie_netto(self):
        skladki_pracownik=round(0.1371*self.wynagrodzenie_brutto,2)
        zdrowotne=round((self.wynagrodzenie_brutto-skladki_pracownik)*0.09,2)
        zdrowotne_odliczenie=round((self.wynagrodzenie_brutto-skladki_pracownik)*0.0775,2)
        kup=111.25
        zaliczka_podstawa=round(self.wynagrodzenie_brutto-kup-skladki_pracownik,2)
        zaliczka_pobrana=round((zaliczka_podstawa*0.18)-zdrowotne_odliczenie-46.33,0)
        netto=round(self.wynagrodzenie_brutto-skladki_pracownik-zdrowotne-zaliczka_pobrana,2)
        return netto

    def skladki_pracodawcy(self):
        skladki_pracodawca=round(self.wynagrodzenie_brutto*0.2074,2)
        return skladki_pracodawca

    def koszty_calkowite(self):
        calosc=round(self.wynagrodzenie_brutto+self.skladki_pracodawcy(),2)
        Pracownik.total += calosc
        return calosc

    def __str__(self):
        return self.imie + ' ' + str(self.wynagrodzenie_netto()) + ' ' + str(self.skladki_pracodawcy()) + ' ' + str(self.koszty_calkowite())

x = int(input('Enter nr: '))

for i in range(x):
    s = input('Enter name and salary: ')
    param_list = s.split(' ')
    pracownik = Pracownik(param_list[0], int(param_list[1]))
    print(pracownik)
print(Pracownik.total)
```

This outputs the following:

```
Enter nr: 2
Enter name and salary: John 2580
John 1863.91 535.09 3115.09
Enter name and salary: Greg 1680
Greg 1237.2 348.43 2028.43
5143.52
```

Note how I take only 1 `input()` per employee to create instead of 2, so you can input the parameters for it on 1 line. The input is converted to a list, split the input by spaces. Then the employee name is `param_list[0]` and his salary is in `param_list[1]`, which is converted to an int.

After all the employee data is printed, the total of the 3rd number is printed. It is stored in the class variable `total` and updated in the `koszty_calkowite` method.

You can even remove the `'Enter name and salary: '` string parameter from the `input()` call so the final output will be like this:

```
John 1863.91 535.09 3115.09
Greg 1237.2 348.43 2028.43
5143.52
```

Keep in mind that the user won't know what to input if you dont print anything

---

**Updated again after new comment**

---

Change the code outside of the class to this:

x = int(input())

```
aList = []
for i in range(x):
    s = input()
    param_list = s.split(' ')
    aList.append(param_list)

for param_list in aList:
    pracownik = Pracownik(param_list[0], int(param_list[1]))
    print(pracownik)
print(Pracownik.total)
```

Now you can enter everything and when you're done it prints everything, and finally the `total` .

```
2
John 2580
Greg 1680
```

Gives:

```
John 1863.91 535.09 3115.09
Greg 1237.2 348.43 2028.43
5143.52
```

Comment: OK it works, thx. But name and salary have to be in one line with space between and output should return the same pattern as I wrote in first post. It's checked automatically so only specifics patterns works ;/

Comment: Thank you for your help but is still one problem. User put name and salary and get the result but result should be returned on the end. At first all input should be given and after that all result should be returned. Could you help me last time please?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot imie variable

```
return str(imie + " " + (self.wynagrodzenie_netto(), self.skladki_pracodawcy(), self.koszty_calkowite()))
```

Using English names for variables might help other users understand your code.

Comment: Next time I'll use English names for variables